# traversing KML files with ogr python

Tags: python, kml, ogr

i'm new to OGR processing and KML format so be gentle:

i've got a series of KML files all containing multiple regions partitioning a larger area in each.  i also have a series of geocoded points for which i want to ask `WITHIN/CONTAINS` queries with respect to the regions.  two questions:

- i don't know how to ENUMERATE all the regions/placemarks contained in the file.  [UPDATE:] thanks to [this hint](https://gist.github.com/capooti/2291849) i guess i can get what i want via a JSON encoding:

  ```
  drv = ogr.GetDriverByName('KML')
  inf = 'path/file.kml'
  ds_in = drv.Open(inf)
  featureTbl = {}
  for kml_lyr in ds_in:
      for feat in kml_lyr:
          ftbl = eval(feat.ExportToJson())
          fname = ftbl['properties']['Name']
          geom = ftbl['geometry']
          featureTbl[fname] = geom
  ```

but there must be a better/XML-parse-like way to get "child" placemark elements?

- since i know the point will only be in one of the regions, i wonder if it is worth the effort of first computing region centroids and asking the `WITHIN/CONTAINS` query of the regions in order of their proximity to the point, rather than just dumbly enumerating all the regions and asking until i get a hit?